# Getting error `The bootnode you want to connect provided a different peer ID than the one you expect` while connecting with main validator

Tags: polkadot, kusama

I am running 4 collator nodes V1, V2, V3, and V4.

V2 and V3 look good and connected perfectly with V1. I am getting the below logs for V2 and V3.

```
Jun 20 16:44:40 testnet-2: 2022-06-20 16:44:40 [Relaychain]  Idle (46 peers), best: #13214589 (0x7c36…37e2), finalized #13214585 (0x2836…f7ff), ⬇ 288.7kiB/s ⬆ 320.0kiB/s
Jun 20 16:44:42 testnet-2: 2022-06-20 16:44:42 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #13214590 (0xfd88…e30b)
Jun 20 16:44:42 testnet-2: 2022-06-20 16:44:42 [Parachain]  Idle (3 peers), best: #0 (0xeacd…ec21), finalized #0 (0xeacd…ec21), ⬇ 24 B/s ⬆ 24 B/s
```

But on V4, I am getting different logs. However, it has the same setup as V2 and V3

```
Jun 20 16:40:31 testnet-4: 2022-06-20 16:40:31 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 313.4 bps, target=#13214548 (48 peers), best: #96064 (0x4ea4…c54d), finalized #95744 (0x0456…d603), ⬇ 252.4kiB/s ⬆ 42.0kiB/s
Jun 20 16:40:32 testnet-4: 2022-06-20 16:40:32 [Relaychain]  The bootnode you want to connect provided a different peer ID than the one you expect: `12D3KooWMVXPbqWRqwertySWDVPjcAQ9XtxqLTVzV4ccox9Y8KNL`.
Jun 20 16:40:35 testnet-4: 2022-06-20 16:40:35 [Parachain]  Idle (3 peers), best: #0 (0xeacd…ec21), finalized #0 (0xeacd…ec21), ⬇ 58 B/s ⬆ 49 B/s
Jun 20 16:40:36 testnet-4: 2022-06-20 16:40:36 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#13214548 (48 peers), best: #96064 (0x4ea4…c54d), finalized #95744 (0x0456…d603), ⬇ 72.9kiB/s ⬆ 37.3kiB/s
```

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Comment: This error was mentioned from other users as well in this issue https://github.com/paritytech/devops/issues/1588 In one of the comments, they verify that all bootnodes have the peer ID as defined in the chainspec. Maybe it is a good place to start.

Comment: @dominique I can not access https://github.com/paritytech/devops/issues/1588

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was reported here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11709 and a fix has recently been merged into `master` here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11851